# How to maintain relationship between two tables.?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have two table one is `USERPROFILE` and another is SKILLS.

Both tables contain data. One user can have many skills and One skill may belongs to many user. **How should I maintain relationship between them..?**

I have added relationship in `UserProfile` Table as one to many with skills.
But when I assign skill object to `userprofile` and try to save it, getting exceptions.
In another case if I create new Skill object and assign to `userprofile` and save `userprofile` object then it is saved. But new id is generated for same skill.

I do not want this, I want to maintain relation between two tables without generation new ids.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a mapping table for `Skills` and `UserProfile` which will keep only id from both tables

It will help you to retrive all skills for a user. And also all users having the skill

Its structure should be like such

```
user_skills
----------------------
ID  |  skill_id  | user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be better to have a user skill mapping table with fields user_id & skill_id. Every time when a user adds a skill, enter it with in mapping table so it will be easier to use this data in future

Answer (score 0):

A join table is necessary (eg. skills_per_user)
With Hibernate use `@OneToMany` with a `@JoinTable`

```
class UserProfile {
  @Id
  private int user_id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(name="skills_per_user",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_skill")}
  )
  private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
}

class Skill {
  @Id
  private int skill_id;
}
```

and join table `skill_per_user` is defined as

```
skill_per_user
---------------------
user_id | skill_id
```